# rust diesel - Invert the value of a boolean field within an update statement

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have a table defined with diesel that has these fields:

```
diesel::table! {
    todos (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        parent_id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        title -> Text,
        done -> Bool,
    }
}
```

Its model is:

```
#[derive(Queryable, QueryableByName, AsChangeset)]
#[diesel(table_name = todos)]
pub struct Todo {
    pub id: i32,
    pub parent_id: Option<i32>,
    pub title: String,
    pub done: bool
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that will toggle the completion of the todo, set it to false if true and vice versa.

I know that I can do it by first querying the record and then setting done to the opposite of the value returned by the select, I was wondering if there was a way to do it in a single update statement (without the select).
In raw SQL I would do `UPDATE todos SET done = NOT done WHERE id = ?`.
In diesel I tried

```
    let todo = diesel::update(todos.find(id))
        .set(done.eq(!done))
        .get_result::<Todo>(conn)
        .unwrap();
```

But this complains that std::ops::Not is not implemented for columns::done. I tried implementing the 'Not' trait but I'm not sure how to convert columns::done to a boolean to return the opposite value (PartialEq is not implemented either).

I've also tried to use `.set(done.ne(done))` but this complains that "the trait `diesel::AsChangeset` is not implemented for `expression::grouped::Grouped<expression::operators::NotEq<columns::done, columns::done>>`".

(I'm using sqlite as a database if that matters).

Can someone help me understand if what I want to do is possible without rawsql or preceding the update with a select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`not`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/dsl/fn.not.html) dsl function here. That corresponds to the `NOT` SQL expression. The full query would be

```rust
let todo = diesel::update(todos.find(id))
        .set(done.eq(dsl::not(done)))
        .get_result::<Todo>(conn)
        .unwrap();
```

As a more general explanation: `set(column.eq())` constructs literally the `SET column =` part of the query. So everything you pass as argument to the `eq()` function will appear on the right side of the `=` sign. It will accept any experession with the correct SQL type.

Diesel does not provide an override for the `!` operator yet. Given the definition of the [underlying trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html) it might be possible to add that to diesel. Consider opening a feature request for that. It should be even possible to manually implement the `std::ops::Not` trait for the corresponding column type. That would require code like:

```rust
impl std::ops::Not for done {
    type Output = dsl::not<Self>;

    fn not(self) -> dsl::not<Self> {
        dsl::not(self)
    }
}
```